# How to delete table cells in libreoffice draw?

Tags: libreoffice

How do I delete a whole table row in Libreoffice Draw. PLease answer quickly because it is due my project is due tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on a row, then go to **Row** >> **Delete**. The selected row will be deleted.

done!

[image]